# how to show this background image

Tags: html, css

you can open it using browser, but I cannot display the background image in these code. what problem it is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="background-image:url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing 1906x810_R1-03.jpg);  
           width:100%;
           background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          position: relative" class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The image you are referencing does not seem to exist.

Comment: There's a space in the image name. I wonder if that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

There two things you need to do:

1. Enclose the URL in quotes.
2. Add some dimensions to the div.

In the updated example below I have added a 500x500 dimension to the div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="background-image:url('https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing 1906x810_R1-03.jpg');  
           width:100%;
           background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          position: relative; width: 500px; height: 500px" class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style="background-image:url('https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing 1906x810_R1-03.jpg');  
       width:100%;
       background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      position: relative" class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a height for the `<div>` with the background image.

**Edit**:
Sorry, did not notice the space in the url. Also make sure that when there is a space in the URL path to the image to enclose the url with quotes.

In this case, since the styling is inlined with double quotes `"`, wrap the url in single quotes `'`.

You could try:

```
  <div style="background-image:url('https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing 1906x810_R1-03.jpg');  
          width:100%;
          height: 100vh;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          position: relative" class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the space with `%20` and set the height of the `div`

```html
<div style="background-image:url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing%201906x810_R1-03.jpg);  
           width:100%;
           height: 300px;
           background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          position: relative" class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to replace the `space` in your image url to `%20` (for more info see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_arbitrary_data))
- `%` values do not work for `width` and `height` because there is no other parent div width for it to be assigned *to* (think as: 100% of *what?*). So we assign our own (non-percentage) `width` and `height` properties to it:

```html
<div style="background-image:url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing%201906x810_R1-03.jpg);  
            width:100vw;
            height:100vh;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            position: relative"
      class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above, you didn't close the double quotes and also assign some height to the div 
and check and remove  the space provided  in the URL link which you have given

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-image:url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing%201906x810_R1-03.jpg);
width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        position: relative"
  class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">;
</div>
```